# How to disable this over scrolling feature on a Samsung Galaxy?

Tags: android, android-layout

While overscrolling the ListView on a Samsung Galaxy phone, an empty blank view arises at the top of the list. How to disable it?

I tried the setOverscrollMode and setOverScrollHeader methods. I could not find a solution.

(sorry I could not post a screen shot)